# What two values to five significant figures should I use for a sign change test to see that $1.228$ (4sf) is a root of $x^4+x^3-2x^2+3x-5=0$?

Tags: roots

What two values to five significant figures should I use for a sign change test to see that $1.228$ (4sf) is a root of $x^4+x^3-2x^2+3x-5=0$?

[image: I have tried 1.2279 and 1.2281. Shows up as incorrect.]

$$f(x)=x^4+x^3-2x^2+3x-5$$
$$f(1.2279)=-0.207149...$$
$$f(1.2281)=-0.205145...$$
$$f(1.3)=0.5731$$
The root is somewhere in the region. After a search on WolframAlpha the root is approximately 1.2481.
$$f(1.2480)=-1.4242...\times 10^{-3}$$
$$f(1.2482)=6.6726...\times 10^{-4}$$

[image: Tried 1.2480 and 1.2482 but the answer is still incorrect.]

I understand that the question may reveal a fault in the form however I am wondering whether there is something I am missing out on?

Comment: Upon inspection the root is clearly 1.248(4sf) so there must be a problem with the question. Taking this as the value it should have been I would test 1.2475 and 1.2485 as they are the extremities of what the root could be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the computed value in hand the root could have been, say, $1.2283475...$ and it would have been $1.228$ to four significant digits yet outside your interval.

The correct interval specification is to include **all the range** where rounding to four significant digits would give $1.228$. That would be **between $1.2275$ and $1.2285$.** Put those bounds in and you should get 2/2 marks.